# How to specify variables for module installations with cpan?

Tags: perl, cpan

During installation with `cpan` (e.g. `cpan XML:Parser`) source code is compiled and sometimes requires additional variables to be set (in the example `EXPATLIBPATH` and `EXPATINCPATH`). `cpan` prints a helpful message what needs to be specified, but says that the specification needs to be ''Makefile'' argument/variables - when running `cpan` that doesn' add up.

I tried to specify environement variables with `env` (only `INC` is recognized for C includes, but the value is trimmed after the first space, so adding a `-L` directive doesn't work) and appending the variables which makes `cpan` search for modules with the variable name and argument. The manpage of `cpan` leaves this (quite crucial) matter completely uncovered. Setting `LD_LIBRARY_PATH` to the prefix I installed `expat` to doesn't work (header files isn't found).

If there's not a generic way, then I'd appreacite a solution for the `cpan XML::Parser` installation. I don't have root permissions on the system, so I need to specify the variables.

I use `cpan` 1.61 with `perl` 5.20.2 on Ubuntu 15.04 with Linux 4.0.1.

Comment: `sudo apt-get install libXML-Parser-perl`

Comment: @serenesat OP said he doesn't have root so that won't work. He cannot install system packages.

Comment: @simbabque: `sudo` doesn't ask for root password and it can be check if someone have privilege to run individual commands as a root using the `sudo`.

Comment: @ser true, but it's a long way assuming that that is the case. And he is asking specifically for how to do stuff with cpan :-)

Comment: This is why nobody likes Perl. I'm also trying to build a module that compiles something in C, and I can find NOTHING to help me specify a custom include path.

Answer (score 1):

You can always do

- install cpanm if you don't have it, with `curl -L https://cpanmin.us | perl - App::cpanminus`
- cpanm --look XML::Parser

That'll download the needed tarballs, unpack, and open a shell inside the distribution. So you're free to do:

- `perl Makefile.PL`
- `make` with any options you need (like setting EXPATLIBPATH)
- `make test`
- `(sudo) make install`

Comment: You don't need cpanm just to download a distribution tarball.

Comment: I know, however, it makes things easier and it looks like he wanted something easy. It'll get/install the dependancies easily.